# how to hide a part of .tex file

Tags: preamble, rendering

I would like to be able to make sure that in the file (.tex) the entire preamble is not seen, in the sense that it is there and actually works, but not seen, so that it preserves all the lines of code that the latter is reserve.
for example:

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{sidenotes}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
```

I would like all these packages to work, but I only see in the compile file:

```
\hiddenpart{in this there is everything that is hidden there, which must not be seen but obviously}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to simply use an editor that allows you to hide parts of the document.

Otherwise, I would simply outsource the preamble to a separate document `preamble.tex` and then load it in the main document with `\input{preamble}`:

```
\input{preamble}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```